# Layout from sinks in Hierarchical layout

Tags: java, jgraphx

**Problem**

Earlier versions (1.x) of JGraphX offered the attribute layoutFromSinks in the mxHierarchicalLayout class. This isn't available anymore and from what I've seen hasn't been for a long time.

The problem of the layout difference is best explained in pictures:

Old JGraphX version, layout from sinks enabled, produces this:

[image]

Newer JGraph versions (most current I tried is 3.4.1.2) produce this:

[image]

As you can see, the old version produces a much cleaner result.

**Question**

Is this hierarchical layout also possible in the latest version of JGraphX and which settings do you need to apply to achieve the same layout?

**Code**

Here's example code that produced the above layouts

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.mxgraph.layout.mxIGraphLayout;
import com.mxgraph.layout.hierarchical.mxHierarchicalLayout;
import com.mxgraph.model.mxICell;
import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;

public class HierarchyLayoutExample extends JFrame {

    mxICell a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;

    public HierarchyLayoutExample() {

        final mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
        Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        try {

            a = (mxICell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "a", 0, 0, 80, 30);
            b = (mxICell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "b", 0, 0, 80, 30);
            c = (mxICell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "c", 0, 0, 80, 30);
            d = (mxICell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "d", 0, 0, 80, 30);
            g = (mxICell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "g", 0, 0, 80, 30);
            h = (mxICell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "h", 0, 0, 80, 30);
            e = (mxICell) graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "e", 0, 0, 80, 30);

            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", a, b);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", a, c);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", c, d);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", e, d);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", g, a);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", b, d);
            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", h, e);

        } finally {
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }

        // define layout
        mxHierarchicalLayout layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
        // layout.setLayoutFromSinks(true); // <== not available anymore

        layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());

        mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(graphComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HierarchyLayoutExample frame = new HierarchyLayoutExample();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(460, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I see, there is no such option atm. You can have a look at `mxHierarchicalLayout.setFineTuning(false)`. If this doesn't fit you needs, I think you have to write your own `mxEdgeStyleFunction` and set it as the edgestyle to be used, then use `mxHierarchicalLayout.setDisableEdgeStyle(false)`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that. Didn't give the expected results. Currently I copied the layout code form the last version where it worked and use that one.